# Memory problem executing python script that creates arrays and figures

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, memory-management, large-data

I will first describe the script and later will publish the code and a way to reproduce the problem, in my machine might not be the case for every machine.

So I have a script that build objects, clouds, with specific properties and export the data to files that is the input to a software called **SHDOM**, this tool analyze radiation properties and can be further read in the following [link](http://coloradolinux.com/shdom/).

The script is its a bit long, sorry in advance:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import gc


def writeDomainFile(type, file_name, temp_vec,
                    lwc, r_effective, dx, dy,
                    height_vec):

    if type == 2:
        assert list(lwc.shape) == list(r_effective.shape), "when the file type is 2 the shapes of lwc and r_effective shold be the same"

    x_lwc, y_lwc, z_lwc = lwc.shape
    x_r_effetive, y_r_effetive, z_r_effetive = r_effective.shape

    fp = open(file_name, 'w')

    # write the file format
    fp.write("{:}\n".format(type))
    # write the number of x, y, z points
    fp.write("{:} {:} {:}\n".format(x_lwc, y_lwc, z_lwc))
    # write the spacing resolution in x and y
    fp.write("{:} {:}\n".format(dx, dy))
    # write the height vector
    fp.write(" ".join(map(str,height_vec)) + "\n")
    # write the temprature vector
    fp.write(" ".join(map(str,temp_vec)) + "\n")

    indices = product(range(x_lwc), range(y_lwc), range(z_lwc))
    print_indices = product(range(1, x_lwc + 1), range(1, y_lwc + 1), range(1, z_lwc + 1))

    if type == 1: # only lwc
        for triplet, print_triplets in zip(indices, print_indices):
            # t = tuple(1 + list(triplet))
            if not lwc[triplet]:
                fp.write("{:} {:} {:} {:}\n".format(*print_triplets, 0))
            else:
                fp.write("{:} {:} {:} {:6.4f}\n".format(*print_triplets, lwc[triplet]))

    elif type == 2:
        for triplet, print_triplets in zip(indices, print_indices):
            # t = tuple(map(lambda x: x + 1, list(triplet)))
            if not lwc[triplet]:
                fp.write("{:} {:} {:} {:} {:}\n".format(*print_triplets, 0, 0))
            else:
                fp.write("{:} {:} {:} {:6.4f} {:4.2f}\n".format(*print_triplets, lwc[triplet], r_effective[triplet]))

    fp.close()
    return

def lapseRateTemp(base_temp, position):
    temp = np.zeros(position.shape)
    temp[0] = base_temp
    temp[1:] = base_temp - 6.5 * position[1:]
    return np.round(temp, 4)

def createCubicCloudDomain(cloud_tick, x_size, y_size,
                            dx, dy, dz, r_effective_option, lwc_option, 
                            cloud_x_size, cloud_y_size):

    # const
    temp0 = 300 # kelvin
    N_x = x_size / dx # number of x points
    N_y = y_size / dy # number of y points
    cld_base = 1.0 # the cloud always start from 1[km] above ground

    x_center = N_x / 2
    y_center = N_y / 2
    prog_x = (cloud_x_size / 2) / dx
    prog_y = (cloud_y_size / 2) / dy
    cloud_x_west = int(x_center - prog_x)
    cloud_x_east = int(x_center + prog_x)
    cloud_y_south = int(y_center - prog_y)
    cloud_y_north = int(y_center + prog_y)

    cloud_x_vec = np.arange(cloud_x_west, cloud_x_east, 1)
    cloud_y_vec = np.arange(cloud_y_south, cloud_y_north, 1)

    for tick in cloud_tick: # cloud_tick might be a vector

        cld_top = cld_base + tick 
        N_z = tick / dz # number of z points

        cloud_z_vec = np.round(np.arange(cld_base, cld_top, dz), 4)

        # temprature
        temp_base = temp0 - 9.8 * cld_base
        temp_vec = lapseRateTemp(temp_base, cloud_z_vec - cld_base,)

        temp_cloud = np.tile(temp_vec,(int(temp_vec.shape[0]), int(temp_vec.shape[0]), 1))
        temp_domain = np.zeros((int(N_x), int(N_y), int(N_z)))
        temp_domain[cloud_x_west:cloud_x_east, cloud_y_south: cloud_y_north, :] = temp_cloud
        plotTemperatureGradient(temp_domain, 'test.png')
        # del temp_cloud
        # del temp_domain
        # gc.collect()

        for r in r_effective_option:
            for l in lwc_option:

                r_effective_cloud = np.full((cloud_x_vec.shape[0],
                                            cloud_y_vec.shape[0],
                                            cloud_z_vec.shape[0]),
                                            r)

                lwc_cloud = np.full((cloud_x_vec.shape[0],
                                    cloud_y_vec.shape[0],
                                    cloud_z_vec.shape[0]),
                                    l)

                r_effective_domain = np.zeros((int(N_x), int(N_y), int(N_z)))

                lwc_domain = np.zeros((int(N_x), int(N_y), int(N_z)))

                # the positions to enter the cloud data
                lwc_domain[cloud_x_west:cloud_x_east, cloud_y_south: cloud_y_north, :] = lwc_cloud
                r_effective_domain[cloud_x_west:cloud_x_east, cloud_y_south: cloud_y_north, :] = r_effective_cloud

                writeDomainFile(2, "test.txt", temp_vec, lwc_domain, r_effective_domain, dx, dy, cloud_z_vec)

                plotGeneratedCloud(lwc_domain, r_effective_domain)
    return

def plotTemperatureGradient(temp_mat, file_name):
    xs, ys, zs = temp_mat.shape
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    X, Y, Z = np.mgrid[:xs, :ys, :zs]
    faltten_data = temp_mat.ravel().astype(np.float16)
    color_map = np.zeros((faltten_data.shape[0], 4))
    # map scalars to colors
    minima =  np.min(faltten_data[np.nonzero(faltten_data)])
    maxima = np.max(faltten_data[np.nonzero(faltten_data)])
    norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=minima, vmax=maxima, clip=True)
    mapper = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap='jet')
    rgba = mapper.to_rgba(faltten_data)

    color_map[:,0:3] = rgba[:, 0:3]
    color_map[:,3] = np.where(faltten_data > 0, 0.07, 0)
    p = ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c=color_map.astype(np.float16))
    ax.set_xlabel('X position [Arb.]')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y position [Arb.]')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z position [Arb.]')
    fig.colorbar(p)
    # plt.title(title)
    plt.savefig(file_name)
    return

def plotGeneratedCloud(lwc, r_effective):
    light_blue = np.array([0, 1, 0.7])
    matrixPlotter(lwc, 'lwc.png', 
                        'Liquid water content of the cloud',
                        light_blue)
    # gc.collect()

    light_pink = np.array([0.9, 0.6, 0.9])
    matrixPlotter(r_effective, 'r_effective.png', 
                        'Effective radius of the cloud',
                        light_pink)
    return

def matrixPlotter(mat, file_name, title, c=np.array([0.2, 0.6, 0])):
    xs, ys, zs = mat.shape
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    X, Y, Z = np.mgrid[:xs, :ys, :zs]
    faltten_data = mat.ravel().astype(np.float16)
    color_map = np.zeros((faltten_data.shape[0], 4))
    color_map[:,0:3] = c
    color_map[:,3] = np.where(faltten_data > 0, 0.07, 0)
    ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c=color_map.astype(np.float16))
    ax.set_xlabel('X position [Arb.]')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y position [Arb.]')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z position [Arb.]')
    plt.title(title)
    plt.savefig(file_name)
    return

# def main():

#     return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # main()
    createCubicCloudDomain([0.5], 2.02, 2.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, [0.5], [1], 0.5, 0.5)
    print("Done")
```

So the problem occur when:

1. I try to export all 3 plots, calling the following blocks:
   `plotGeneratedCloud(lwc_domain, r_effective_domain)` or 
   `temp_cloud = np.tile(temp_vec,(int(temp_vec.shape[0]), int(temp_vec.shape[0]), 1))
   temp_domain = np.zeros((int(N_x), int(N_y), int(N_z)))
   temp_domain[cloud_x_west:cloud_x_east, cloud_y_south: cloud_y_north, :] = temp_cloud
   plotTemperatureGradient(temp_domain, 'test.png')`
2. When I try to create more then 1 object (cloud), so calling the function with:
   `createCubicCloudDomain([0.5, 0.6], 2.02, 2.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, [0.5, 0.4], [1, 0.3], 0.5, 0.5)`
3. increasing the domain size like:
   `createCubicCloudDomain([0.5], 4.02, 4.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, [0.5], [1], 0.5, 0.5)`

The type of error I'm getting is the following:

> File
>   "C:\Users\davidsr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py",
>   line 396, in draw
>       self.figure.draw(self.renderer)   File "C:\Users\davidsr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py",
>   line 38, in draw_wrapper
>       return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\davidsr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py",
>   line 1735, in draw
>       mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(   File "C:\Users\davidsr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py",
>   line 137, in _draw_list_compositing_images
>       a.draw(renderer)   File "C:\Users\davidsr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py",
>   line 38, in draw_wrapper
>       return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\davidsr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py",
>   line 291, in draw
>       sorted(self.collections,   File "C:\Users\davidsr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py",
>   line 292, in 
>       key=lambda col: col.do_3d_projection(renderer),   File "C:\Users\davidsr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\art3d.py",
>   line 538, in do_3d_projection
>       vxs, vys, vzs, vis = proj3d.proj_transform_clip(xs, ys, zs, renderer.M)   File
>   "C:\Users\davidsr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\proj3d.py",
>   line 214, in proj_transform_clip
>       vec = _vec_pad_ones(xs, ys, zs)   File "C:\Users\davidsr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\proj3d.py",
>   line 189, in _vec_pad_ones
>       return np.array([xs, ys, zs, np.ones_like(xs)]) MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (4, 2040200) and data type float64

I understand the problem is memory issues, so I thought that deleting the arrays once finish with them might solve the problem, so i used `del` function or even using the garbage collector solution used in the following question: [How can I explicitly free memory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316767/how-can-i-explicitly-free-memory-in-python)

Would appreciate some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `figure` object persists in memory if you don't `.close()` it first, and it includes all the data it's plotting.

Try putting a `plt.close(fig)` before the `return` statement in `matrixPlotter`.  Then your `gc.collect()` statements should be able to catch it if it's not collected by `matplotlib` ([and I don't think it is](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8519)).